# Adding fields to the Business Card

Tags: user-profile, business-card

How do you add fields to the business card under my profile? I have created  a custom property for linked in profile and I want this to display on the card.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a property on the Property Page in the UPA admin pages called 'Show in the profile properties section of the user's profile page'

Comment: I have "Show in the profile properties section of the user's profile page" ticked but I only can see it if I press More information. Is there any way to display it by default?

Comment: No, there isn't. Unless you customize the actual profile page.