# Manipulate my site - business card - Person.asxp

Tags: my-site

I'm trying to add fields (custom) to the business card. I want to use the default Person.aspx from SharePoint but I can't manipulate what fields I want to display. I've tried "User Profile Property" in CA without any luck.

I read a old question that the only way to add new fields is to make a new Person.aspx and then re-route. [LINK - Adding fields in Business card](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/23518/adding-fields-to-the-business-card) @Wictor Wilen MCA MCM MVP do mention that the only way to add fields are to create a new Person.aspx site.

Then I thought, what if I just hide the "business card" with CSS and then rebuild it with JS (I don't want post-backs to the server). All the fields I need are in "ms-my-profileDetails" (ID) on the site, but without any class/ID.

My problem is that if a field is blank/empty it will not be listed. Since I don't get any ID / classes on the listed fields, I don't know what each fields are (name, phone, e-mail ..)

Is there a way to get ID / Class in the list (ms-my-profileDetails)??

If NO, what's the best way (without SharePoint Designer) to create a new Person.aspx?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply put, you can do this in visual studio:

Create a copy of person.aspx to _layouts

Redirect to the custom version using AdditionalPageHeaders delegate control

Remove/add in custom control templates

Deploy

Profile properties are in this format:

```
<SPSWC:ProfilePropertyValue TitleMode="false" PropertyName="FirstName" runat="server"/>
<SPSWC:ProfilePropertyValue PropertyName="MyCustomProperty" runat="server"/>
```